# Grails dynamic select list javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, grails

I have a dynamic select list on the main template form that will read the values from the previous select list and populate the choices accordingly.  This select list works great on the create screen however on the edit screen the select list will show all choices from the list not those just associated with the select list above.  In my main layout page I have an onload function that is firing and showing the correct consultant id according to the alert.

My onload function is

```
// This is called when the page loads to initialize contracts
var zselect = document.getElementById('consultant')
var zopt = zselect.options[zselect.selectedIndex]
window.alert("consultant value is" + zopt.value)
${remoteFunction(controller:'cdeEvaluation', action:'ajaxGetContracts', params:"/'id='/    + zopt.value", onSuccess:'updateContract(e)')}}
```

Here is the onchange event code which is working correctly

```
function updateContract(e) {
    // The response comes back as a bunch-o-JSON
    var contracts = eval("(" + e.responseText + ")")    // evaluate JSON

    if (contracts) {
        var rselect = document.getElementById('contract')

        // Clear all previous options
        var l = rselect.length

        while (l > 0) {
            l--
            rselect.remove(l)
        }

        // Rebuild the select
        for (var i=0; i < contracts.length; i++) {
            var contract = contracts[i]
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.text = contract.contractName
            opt.value = contract.id
            try {
                rselect.add(opt, null) // standards compliant; doesn't work in IE
            }
            catch(ex) {
                rselect.add(opt) // IE only
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The controller code is

```
def ajaxGetContracts = {
     def cdeConsultant = CdeConsultant.get(params.id)
     render cdeConsultant?.contracts as JSON
}
```

My gsp code for these two selects is

```
<g:select id="consultant" class="form-control" label="Consultant" required="" name="consultant"  from="${CdeConsultant.list()}" optionValue="ccf_consultant_firm"  value="${cdeEvaluationInstance?.consultant}" optionKey="id" noSelection="['':'Select Consultant']"
    onchange="${remoteFunction(
        controller:'cdeEvaluation', 
        action:'ajaxGetContracts', 
        params:'\'id=\' + escape(this.value)', 
        onSuccess:'updateContract(e)')}"
></g:select>

<g:select class="form-control"  label= "Contract*"  name="contract" id="contract" from="${Contract.list()}" optionValue="contractName" optionKey="id" noSelection="['':'Select Contract']" value="${cdeEvaluationInstance?.contract}"></g:select>
```

I have tried a variety of options in the from= and the window.onload function and can't seem to get it to function properly.  Thanks!

Comment: If you are seeing the `alert()` in both pages but the select is not working in the edit page, then I would debug the JS function `updateContract`. I'm guessing either the `contact` data being eval'ed is not right on the edit page (thus not entering the `if (contracts)` or else the subsequent DOM manipulation code is not working. Try stepping through that JS code with Firebug/Chrome debugger or else add a bunch of `alert` or `console.log` statements to see what is happening.

Comment: I have added some alerts and messages to the application.  in the window onload function the call sees the right consultant and makes the call to the controller where the correct list is returned so it appears that everything is functioning as needed but the call to the updateContract function never happens.

Comment: Forgot to mention  If I remove the e from 'updateContract(e)' the function will be called but won't update the list

Comment: I found where I had a g:javascript library=jquery on template page.  If I remove that then the select list narrows down as required however the correct option isn't shown as selected on the page.  Any ideas?

Comment: If you still have this issue take a look at `ajaxdependancyselection` plugin. Might be helpful.